# iOS Facebook Connect news feed

Tags: objective-c, facebook-graph-api

I need to get the user news feed data.

Currently I'm using this:
`[[FBManager defaultManager]getFBRequestWithGraphPath:@"me/home" params: andDelegate:self];`

and then:

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result {   
if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) 
    result = [result objectAtIndex:0];}
```

result gives me a bunch of data. But how do Extract these individually? Maybe the name and message for example??

Answer (score 0):

I'd change from using requestWithGraphPath to requestWithMethodName.

Here's the sample code:

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT post_id, actor_id, message FROM stream WHERE filter_key = 'others '", @"query",
                                   nil];
```

`[facebook   requestWithMethodName: @"fql.query"
        andParams: params
        andHttpMethod: @"POST"
        andDelegate: self];`

Then in the request didLoad method:

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result 
{

    if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) 
          result = [result objectAtIndex:0];

     friendID = [[result objectForKey:@"actor_id"]copy];
     friendMsg = [[result objectForKey:@"message"]copy];
}
```

Facebook documentations on the iOS FB Connect SDK are very blend. It helps if you know a bit of SQL(fql) :)